# Convert Uint8Array into hex string equivalent in node.js

Tags: node.js, string-conversion

I am using node.js v4.5. Suppose I have this Uint8Array variable.

```
var uint8 = new Uint8Array(4);
uint8[0] = 0x1f;
uint8[1] = 0x2f;
uint8[2] = 0x3f;
uint8[3] = 0x4f;
```

This array can be of any length but let's assume the length is 4.

I would like to have a function that that converts `uint8` into the hex string equivalent.

```
var hex_string = convertUint8_to_hexStr(uint8);
//hex_string becomes "1f2f3f4f"
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use [`Buffer.from()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_arraybuffer_byteoffset_length) and subsequently use [`toString('hex')`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end):

```
let hex = Buffer.from(uint8).toString('hex');
```

Comment: This is a good answer for the Node.js use case, but it is not compatible with Deno or the browser.

Comment: @FilipSeman good thing the question was tagged with [tag:node.js] then :D

Answer (score 15):

Another solution:

Base function to convert int8 to hex:

```
// padd with leading 0 if <16
function i2hex(i) {
  return ('0' + i.toString(16)).slice(-2);
}
```

`reduce`:

```
uint8.reduce(function(memo, i) {return memo + i2hex(i)}, '');
```

Or `map` and `join`:

```
Array.from(uint8).map(i2hex).join('');
```

Comment: This does not padd correctly when the decimal value is <16. Here's a fixed version `uint8.reduce(function(memo, i) {
    return memo + ("0"+i.toString(16)).slice(-2);
}, '');`

Comment: Second method works only for an Array but not Uint8Array, as the map function tries to write a string to the array (for Uint8Array it is casted to a number and evaluates to zero when there is a letter in the hex number). Workaround is to use Array.from(uint8) instead of uint8.

Comment: Slight modernization: `uint8.reduce((t, x) => t + x.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'), '')`

Answer (score 6):

`Buffer.from` has multiple overrides.

If it is called with your `uint8` directly, it unnecessarily **copies** its content because it selects `Buffer.from( <Buffer|Uint8Array> )` version.

You should call `Buffer.from( arrayBuffer[, byteOffset[, length]] )` version which does not copy and just creates a **view** of the buffer.

```
let hex = Buffer.from(uint8.buffer,uint8.byteOffset,uint8.byteLength).toString('hex');
```

Comment: Relevant documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromarraybuffer-byteoffset-length

Answer (score 3):

Buffer is nodeJS specific.

This is a version that works everywhere:

```js
const uint8 = new Uint8Array(4);
uint8[0] = 0x1f;
uint8[1] = 0x2f;
uint8[2] = 0x3f;
uint8[3] = 0x4f;

function convertUint8_to_hexStr(uint8) {
  Array.from(uint8)
    .map((i) => i.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
    .join('');
}

convertUint8_to_hexStr(uint8);
```